# WPF DoubleAnimtation Completed Event cause memory leak?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, memory-leaks

I have a C# WPF application need to run 24-hours, and it contains a lot of animation.
I found out that if I use the completed event of the animation, the parent object cannot be destruct, and then the app becomes laggy in less than an hour. Is it a bug of wpf or something else??
Anyone experience before?? (newbies to wpf)

```
private void AnimUpperBGFade(Canvas canvas, int delay = 0)
    {
        DoubleAnimation animY = new DoubleAnimation();
        ScaleTransform S = new ScaleTransform();
        animY.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delay);
        animY.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(RECT_FADE_MS));
        animY.From = 1.0;
        animY.To = 0.0;
        // If I add the completed event, the class object will not destruct
        /*
        animY.Completed += (sender, e)
            {
                // some callback function here
            };
         */
        canvas.RenderTransform = S;
        S.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, animY);
    }
```

Comment: do you also remove the eventhandler of the Event when the Completed-Event is raised?

Comment: Opps, i found out that the completed event probably not the culprit of the leak. It was the animation does not finished and I change to another page, then it will keep the reference and leak. But if I make sure the animation is end then change to other page then no problem. Thanks Jehof.